# How do I index a dictionary of multiple lists using a list of indexes?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7, indexing

I'm on Python 2.7.3.
If I have a dictionary of lists, like this:

```
>>> x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,5]
>>> x2 = range(11,20)
>>> mydict = {'first':x1,'second':x2}
```

... and the lists are equal size...

```
>>> len(mydict['second']) == len(mydict['first'])
True
```

How do I use a list of indexes like this:

```
>>> ind = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

To get the values from both lists in my dictionary?  I have tried to use the "ind" list to index, but continuously get an error whether ind is a list or tuple like this:

```
>>> mydict['second'][ind]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not set
```

I realize that the list isn't an integer, but each value in the set is an integer.  Is there any way to get to the x1[ind] and x2[ind ] without iterating a counter" in a loop?

Don't know if it matters, but I have the index list already that I got from finding the unique values like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ux1 = np.unique(x1, return_index = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
indexgetter = itemgetter(*ind)
indexed1 = indexgetter(mydict['first'])
indexed2 = indexgetter(mydict['second'])
```

note that in my example, `indexed1` and `indexed2` will be `tuple` instances, not `list` 
instances.  The alternative is to use a list comprehension:

```
second = mydict['second']
indexed2 = [second[i] for i in ind]
```

Comment: Brilliant!  179 lines of fail and you solve it in 3.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
getter = itemgetter(*ind)
getter(mydict['second']) # returns a tuple of the elements you're searching for.
```